# Measure CountIf with range in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, countif

I'm trying to count records in a range.

```
Measure= COUNT('CRM Records'[DaysOpen], >5, <10)
```

Comment: Hi, your new to stackoverflow, please read this guide to asking a question for future reference.https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. If the answer helps you please accept the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the count in a [CALCULATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/calculate-function-dax) function, and use [FILTER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/filter-functions-dax)

```
measure = CALCULATE(COUNT('CRM Records), FILTER('CRM Records, 'CRM Records[DaysOpen] >5 && 'CRM Records[DaysOpen] < 10))
```

If you are new to DAX try this [Stairway to DAX](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairways/stairway-to-dax-and-power-bi) that covers items like CALCULATE and FILTER functions